# Ajax form progress redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form which I have been trying to get a progress bar to work on. This form is in joomla and I have managed to get a Ajax progress bar to show when a file is being uploaded. However the usual habit of the form is that when it has been submitted, it will go to item page the form is associated with and will give a confirmation on that page saying that yes it was saved.

However with this new Ajax progress bar, the bar gets to 100% and looking in firebug it shows that both the POST and GET were both successful but the problem is that the browser stays on the form page without the original redirect to the same GET url?

Some of the code is as follows:

```
    JHTML::_('behavior.mootools');
    JHTML::_('behavior.formvalidation');

    $document =& JFactory::getDocument();

    $document->addScript('components/com_component/assets/validate.js');
    $document->addScript('jquery-1.7.js');
    $document->addScript('jquery.form.js');
    $document->addScript('custom.js');

    <form action="index.php" method="post" name="nameForm" id="idForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-validate">
<input type="file" name="item_file" id="item_file"/></td>
```

Then in the custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

    $('#item_file').change(function(){
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    $('#submit').change(function(){
        $('#progress').removeClass('hide');
    });


    var options = {

    beforeSend: function()
    {
        $("#progress").show();
        //clear everything
        $("#bar").width('0%');
        $("#message").html("");
        $("#percent").html("0%");
    },

    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete)
    {
        $("#bar").width(percentComplete+'%');
        $("#percent").html(percentComplete+'%');

    },

    success: function()
    {
        $("#bar").width('100%');
        $("#percent").html('100%');

    },

    complete: function(response)
    {
        $("#message").html("<font color='green'>"+response.responseText+"</font>");
    },

    complete: function()
    {

    },

    error: function()
    {


    }

};

     $("#idForm").ajaxForm(options);
});
```

Is there anything I can add to the custom.js so that the default action or redirect will still take place when the upload progress bar is complete.

Thanks.

Comment: You used a *font* element? yikes.

Comment: So on success you want to redirect the page? So set the window.location.href in the success or complete method.

Answer (score 0):

Change your on success call of Ajax to go to the destination page:

```
  success: function()
    {
        $("#bar").width('100%');
        $("#percent").html('100%');
        //Go to new page
        window.location.href= 'index.php';

    },
```

Comment: Thanks that does do a redirect but to the root of the website and not to the item page that the form is associated to. Right after clicking submit and the progress is finished there is a GET url shown in firebug.. ex. 'index.php?option=com_component&view=item&id=38' This would be the url that needs to be redirected to. How would this be possible..

Comment: Also like to add that the url is always different as different items and different forms so not as easy as just putting window.location.href='index.php?option=com_component&view=item&id=38';

Comment: Send the required data down from server to the client to make the query params of the URL.. So it will be - success: function(data){ //construct url for redirect based on data in data object coming from server };

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem , I have solved it.

That works 100% ;)

Add

> action="javascript:void(0)"

to your form and use

> window.location.href

function inside your success of ajax.